# Naudio- Multiple sound device playback and recording issue

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

i am using WaveOut and WaveInEvent to record sound from multiple usb sound devices and playing it back to them. i am talking about 4-6 external usb sound cards that i have to record and playback at the same time all together.

so it means that for every sound device i have one object of WaveOut with the soundDevice ID and one object of WaveInEvent with the same SoundDevice ID (for record&playback).

my c# project throws mmexeption with explanation :"unspecified problem" when i am calling to the WaveInEvent.startRecording(). sometime it happens in the init of the WaveOut with the stream.

i thought that maybe there is a limitation of opening sound card devices for play&record or maybe naudio cant support it.

so is the limitation exist? or maybe i have to use diffrent object then WaveOut and WaveInEvent when handling multiple sound card device?

Comment: 4-6 USB audio devices is a bad idea from the start.  Try a simple test - open 6 instances of winamp, direct each instance to one usb device, and try to play them at the same time.  if you add recording to that, I'm sure that you will reach breaking point soon.

Comment: do you want me to record with winamp? does it has that option?
i will chack if winamp can handle playing for all the devices because in my previous check Naudio didnt handle it(playing all devices without recording them, gave me the same exeption).

Comment: Try playing and recording all of the devices with a software that you know it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried to play on all devices from Winamp and when I got to the forth sound card it didn't play.

I tried to plug one sound card to a different USB hub of the pc (not different port at the same hub, a new port on a different hub) and suddenly it works! also with Naudio. now i can open all of them to playback and record. I haven't tried massive check yet but its looking good.

it's seems like that the problem was that I overloaded the usb hub. I don't know if it because the usb hub doesn't has enough bandwidth or because something that belongs to voltage issue.